# How could i get value from array of array in laravel

Tags: mysql, arrays, laravel

Helper, 
I can fetch value of fname, lname and so on.., But I'm struggling to fetch value of address1, city.., where my array is,

```
Array
(
    [id] => 172
    [fname] => Someone
    [lname] => Sombody
    [gender] => Male
    [phno] => 0123456789
    [addresses] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 71
                    [user_id] => 172
                    [address1] => somewhere
                    [city] => some city
                    [state] => some state
                    [country] => India
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 72
                    [user_id] => 172
                    [address1] => someplace
                    [city] => specified city
                    [state] => specified state
                    [country] => India
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over subarray, for example:

```
@foreach ($array['addresses'] as $address)
    {{ $address['city'] }}
    {{ $address['address1'] }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: But brother I can get only value of [0] what to do for [1]

Comment: @SamuelHenry this code should print `city` and `address1` for all addresses in the array.

Comment: sry don't mistake me,  For example,  only I'm getting  {address1} value as {somewhere}. I wanna get both {somewhere} and {someplace}. foreach should do but It not..,

Comment: Sry, @Alexey Mezenin, actually I also has another error so y I got that. Thanks mr...

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to this in Laravel way, you can use a `collection`.

Here is an example

```
 $collection = collect(Your array);

$filtered = $collection->only(['addresses']);
$filtered->all();
//it will return the your desired collection
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can access by `$baseArray['addresses'][0]['address1']` and so on.

But what you probably want is something like:

```
@foreach ($array as $baseArray['addresses'])
    {{ $address['city'] }}
    {{ $address['address1'] }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks bro yours first one is working, second code is with an error